# How can I read ODS files in jupyter notebook? If there is a way , can I use all the parameters like skiprows in pandas.read_excel in them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, ods

The Python library pandas can read Excel and CSV spreadsheets and convert them to pandas.DataFrame with pandas.read_excel(file) and pandas.read_csv(file) command. In which it does not support ODS files.

Comment: Use Excel to open the file and save it as `.xlsx` or `.csv`?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please can you give us more information about your attempts? See the guidelines of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post great questions :) Take a look also to the StackOverflow [tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.